# Failed to download the Package. End of Central Directory record could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, directory, nuget-package

I just install visual studio 2022. And create a ASP.NET Core Web API proj but when i check the directory it was wrong and when I tried to install any package from NuGet Package manager this was not installing.[Error on VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtoKj.png)[Folder Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/528CH.png)[Inside the Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcszs.png)

I was expecting this at least download the packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, you can try disabling the agents in your system one by one, and then try to do a NuGet download. After each disabling the proxy, check if the download was successful. This can help you determine which proxy is causing the problem, and once you've found the exact proxy issue, you can check the agent's configuration and make sure it's correctly allowing NuGet to download, or add the NuGet feed or related domain name to the proxy's whitelist to prevent the proxy from blocking access to these sites.

If that doesn't work, you can try connecting to another network, possibly one that doesn't use a proxy, to see if the download works. At the same time, you can also try to use .NET CLI command installation package, for example:

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore --version 7.0.13.
```

If the above methods still do not succeed in the installation, please provide more information and a detailed description of the problem.

Comment: This issue is resolved now. It was due to some Agent working in background interrupts the downloading. When I disables these Agents then it works fine and successfully install the packages.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of the problem and the related problems shown in the picture, I suggest that you can solve the problem in the following aspects:
First, you could to try changing your NuGet package source to "https://www.nuget.org/api/v2". This is a common NuGet package source configuration that may be related to your problem. In the NuGet Package Manager, check and modify your source settings to make sure it points to the correct address: [image]

Second, since you are using .NET 6.0, make sure you download the NuGet package that is compatible with the .NET 6.0 version. Check if the packages you need have versions that match .NET 6.0. In the NuGet Package Manager, select the appropriate package version for .NET 6.0.

Finally, check your network connection and routing settings to make sure there are no network issues interfering with the download of the package. Sometimes, network configuration issues may affect the download and installation of packages. Make sure your network connection is working properly and there are no firewall or proxy settings that are affecting the download of the package.

Comment: I have done with these steps but It's not solve my problem. Still facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the NuGet cache can be corrupted, and you can try to clean up the NuGet cache by Nuget Package Manager [image]

Or use: nuget locals all -clear.
If you're still having trouble, please post the latest details of the issue.

Comment: Actually I have some Agent installed in my system like ForcePoint. May be these interrupt the downloads. What your suggestions?